# Removing Address Asking in Prestashop

Tags: prestashop

I want to disable the address asking feature in prestashop.
Is there any way to do it.
I will be only hosting the virtual products in prestashop 1.5.3.1.

Comment: That may be some what tricky, but i think for Virtual products, PS should not ask for addresses. I am not sure about this feature, but let me check PS, and then i will confirm you and will provide you theoretical details how to do this.

Comment: Maybe you can use the information here: http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/234783-virtual-downloads-delivery-address/

Answer (score 1):

If you choose "Virtual product" in Information section, Shipping tab will automatically disappear. That's the point.